# Regex to match everything except undefined XML entitites

Tags: php, xml, regex

XML, unlike HTML, only knows four named entities: `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;` and `&quot;`.

I have been using XMLWriter in PHP to write lots of data to an XML file, and first I escape the desired text, which gives me some other entities, such as `&Acirc;` and `&curren;`.

I have tried the following regex:

`&(?!(apos|quot|[gl]t|amp);)`

but it only matches the `&` and not `&Acirc;` or `&current;`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping symbols in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499224/escaping-symbols-in-php) by the same OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `\w+;` to your expression, it will work:

```
&(?!(?:apos|quot|[gl]t|amp);)\w+;
```

But you are better off using the correct escaping function from the beginning that doesn't give you these problems.

Comment: To clarify this answer, the negative lookahead `(?!...)` doesn't capture anything, you need the \w to actually capture it.

Comment: Correct escaping function?
I am using `htmlentities($text)` and it escapes everything, which includes some of the undefined XML entities so I have to manually delete them.

Comment: @ToniPerić, perhaps use `htmlentities($text, ENT_XML1)`

Comment: @ToniPerić, and if that doesn't work, it may be better to write your own escaping function, instead of writing a function to reverse the process.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) (with a list of allowed tags) instead of htmlentities()?

Answer (score 0):

Do not escape the entities yourself. Let the XMLWriter do the needed escaping.

```
$writer= new XMLWriter;
$writer->openMemory();
$writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$writer->startElement('root');
$writer->text('A & B & <C>');
$writer->endElement();

$writer->endDocument();
echo $writer->outputMemory(TRUE);
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>A &amp; B &amp; &lt;C&gt;</root>
```